# Android NDK unable to debug native code with two gradle plugins

Tags: android, debugging, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

I'm using NDK with the experimental gradle plugin, and initially I was able to debug my native code.

Then I saw this issue https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/119 and this blog post http://frogermcs.github.io/json-parsing-with-flatbuffers-in-android/.
This approach would be great, because I could use the stable gradle plugin for android specific code, and the experimental gradle plugin for the native code, witch would be great to use use databinding for example.
I was able to use this structure, but I lost the ability to debug native code.

I have created a sample project that illustrate my problem.
https://github.com/4brunu/AndroidNDKDebug

In there you can find two projects.
The first one "hello-jni-one-gradle-plugin", only use the experimental gradle plugin, and I'm able to debug the native code.
The second one "hello-jni-two-gradle-plugins", I use the stable gradle plugin for android specific code, and the experimental gradle plugin for the native code, and I'm unable to debug the native code.

Am I doing something wrong?
Could you help me enable native code debug in the second project please?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using the same setup in one of my projects, with Android Studio 2.1-preview5, gradle-experimental 0.7.0-alpha5, and gradle plugin 2.1.0-alpha5, and debugging works.

The secret missing step is to add the path to your non-stripped libs to the debugger: `lib/build/intermediates/binaries/release/obj/ABI`

[image: ndk debug symbol directories]

Comment: Thanks for you anwser, but I cound't found that path...
Can you please take a look at my sample project? Thanks
https://github.com/4brunu/AndroidNDKDebug

Comment: After you'll have triggered one build, your path should be `shared/build/intermediates/binaries/release/obj/x86` if you're using an x86 device or the emulator, `shared/build/intermediates/binaries/release/obj/armeabi-v7a` if you're using an armeabi-v7a device. Maybe you also need to update your plugin versions in your sample, at least to 2.0.0 (stable) and 0.6.0 (experimental)

Comment: with newer gradle, path may be like shared/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/